# iOS : How to create a close button that sits on the edge of a UIView with rounded corners (using IB)?

Tags: ios, uiview, rounded-corners

### Background:

I am working on an iPad app that will pop a custom view when the user clicks on an image.
I want the view to have rounded corners and a close button ( red x in a circle ) that sits on right top edge.

The button in half inside and half outside the view.... Take a look at the Kayak or Zynga Poker apps to see what I am talking about.

Question : If I create the view programmatically and add the button, it works.

However, I really want to user a nib to create the view so I can design the view correctly. So when I call self.layer.maskToBounds = YES on the view ( to create the rounded corners with a radius of 25 ), it clips my button ( since its half in and half out ). How do I retain my button without it getting clipped and still have rounded corners ?

Comment: Are you calling maskToBounds on the button or on the view that contains the button?  If you want rounded corners on the button, wouldn't you call maskToBounds on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are using a view and a button. What you might try is using a third container view (with clear background) in which you place your original view and your button. The button will need to be on top of the view, so to speak, so it is not obscured by your view. But that should allow you to have properly rounded corners on your view (not the container view) and have your button fully visible.

Comment: This was something I really didnt want to do but looks like that is the only way to go.... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Some settings, such as maskToBounds, cornerRadius, aren't available in IB.  You can create the entire view using a NIB except it won't have rounded corners in IB and in viewDidLoad you set just those properties that couldn't be set in IB.

Comment: I am not worried about setting these properties in code.... In fact that is what I AM doing after setting up the view in the IB. THe problem is setting the code cuts off the corners ( like expected ) but also clips the button in half since it is 50% outside the view.